# Python: Folium HTML Popups

Tags: python, html, popup, tooltip, folium

How can I add a `html` popup to a `Folium choropleth` map?

I have no problems doing this for `Folium.CircleMarker` but cannot find a way for Choropleth maps.

My approach so far is:

```
   import folium
   import pandas as pd


m = folium.Map(location=[LAT, LONG], tiles = 'Stamen Terrain', zoom_start=8)


mm = folium.Choropleth(
    geo_data=polygons,
    name='Number of Points in Shape File',
    data=df,
    columns=['shape_name', 'number_of_points'],
    key_on='feature.properties.shape_name',
    fill_color='Greens',
    highlight=True,
    smooth_factor=0,
    threshold_scale=[0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 15, 20, 35, 50],
    legend_name= 'Number of Points within Polygon').add_to(m)
```

Here comes the part of adding a tooltip when hovering over a plotted shapefile from `polygons`.

```
mm.geojson.add_child(folium.features.GeoJsonTooltip(
        fields=['shape_name', 'number_of_points'],
        aliases=['Polygon Name: ', 'Number of Points within Boundary: '],
        style=('background-color: grey; color: white;')
        ))
```

How can I add a html popup when hovering over one of the plotted shapefiles in Folium, e.g. for incorporating images?

Superimposing the plotted data with a `PolyLine` Feature?

Answer (score 0):

I saw an implementation for popups over choropleth in Folium in this post: [How to step up your Folium Choropleth Map skills](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-step-up-your-folium-choropleth-map-skills-17cf6de7c6fe)

I report below part of the code, but credits are for the original author at the link above:

```
# Add hover functionality.
style_function = lambda x: {'fillColor': '#ffffff', 
                            'color':'#000000', 
                            'fillOpacity': 0.1, 
                            'weight': 0.1}
highlight_function = lambda x: {'fillColor': '#000000', 
                                'color':'#000000', 
                                'fillOpacity': 0.50, 
                                'weight': 0.1}
NIL = folium.features.GeoJson(
    data = final_df,
    style_function=style_function, 
    control=False,
    highlight_function=highlight_function, 
    tooltip=folium.features.GeoJsonTooltip(
        fields=['state','wills'],
        aliases=['state','wills'],
        style=("background-color: white; color: #333333; font-family: arial; font-size: 12px; padding: 10px;") 
    )
)
sample_map2.add_child(NIL)
sample_map2.keep_in_front(NIL)
```